# How can I use the same object in an external class?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi2

Hellow guys.
I have few scripts containing different classes and I have main script where I use those classes and make them work together and it all did work fine untill i wanted to use object created in main.py script in another script.

I DO NOT WANT TO create new object in my not-main script. I want to use existing object, created in main.py in different script.

I connect to GSM modem via serial port on GPIO so i can use ATcommands to "talk" to it. I have powerOn.py class (which i'm not gonna post here) where i have some pin setup, serial.py script where i have some methods which allow me to communicate via serial port within a serialClass and my latest ugly child gsmSMS.py script (I'm currently working on it) where i want to have some methods to sendSMS, openSMS, listSMSs, delteSpecificSMS, deleteAllSMS etc. And inside those methods i need send() and receive() from serialConnection but without creating a new object in this sript.

But here is the problem:

My main.py script (well.. part of it):

```
def main():
try:
    global running
    running = True
    global atCommandLineOn
    atCommandLineOn = True
    with ooGSM.RPiToGsmPins() as modemGSM:
        with aGsmSerial.serialConnection() as serialGSM:
            if modemGSM.czyWlaczany==True:
                sms = aGsmSMS.sms(serialGSM) #THIS WHERE PROBLEM STARTS!!!!
            else:
                print("ERROR: Turn on the modem!!!")
            if atCommandLineOn==True:
                print("AT command line is ON.")
            else:
                print("AT command line is OFF.")
            while running==True:
                print("Write command:\n   :: ", end="")
                command = str(input())
                menu(command, modemGSM, serialGSM)
                time.sleep(0.5)
except OSError:
    print("asdasdfsdff")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The magic happens in menu() but since it works correctly i decided not to coppy the code.

This is my serial.py

```
class serialConnection():
IDLE = 0; SENDING = 1; RECEIVING = 2;
UNKNOWN = 0; COMPLETE_OK = 1; COMPLETE_ERROR = 2; NOTCOMPLETE = 3; EMPTY = 4;

def __init__(self, devicePath="/dev/ttyAMA0", timeout=3):
    self.STATE = ["IDLE", "SENDING", "RECEIVING"]
    self.STATE_RESPONSE = ["UNKNOWN" ,"COMPLETE_OK", "COMPLETE_ERROR", "NOTCOMPLETE", "EMPTY"]
    self.mySerial = serial.Serial(devicePath)
    self.mySerial.timeout = timeout
    self.state = self.STATE[serialConnection.IDLE]

def __enter__(self):
    return self

def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
    self.mySerial.flushInput()
    self.mySerial.flushInput()
    self.mySerial.close()
    print("Serial connection closed")

def send(self, message, printWhatIsSent=True):
    command = message + "\r"
    if self.state==self.STATE[serialConnection.IDLE] and self.mySerial.isOpen(): #THIS IS WHERE PROGRAM STOPS
        self.responseState=self.STATE_RESPONSE[serialConnection.UNKNOWN]
        self.state = self.STATE[serialConnection.SENDING]
        messageInBytes = self.str2byte(command)
        self.mySerial.write(messageInBytes)
        self.mySerial.flushOutput()
        self.state = self.STATE[serialConnection.IDLE]
        if printWhatIsSent==True:
            print(">>>>> Command sent: " + message)
    else:
        print("!!!ERROR: Command did not send")

def str2byte(self, message):
    return bytearray(message, "ascii")

def receive(self, saveResponseToFile=True, printResponseStatus=True, printResponse=True):
    bytesToRead = self.mySerial.inWaiting()
    responseReadyToSave = "saveResponseToFile=False"
    if self.state==self.STATE[serialConnection.IDLE] and self.mySerial.isOpen():
        self.state = self.STATE[serialConnection.RECEIVING]
        while self.state==self.STATE[serialConnection.RECEIVING]:
            modemResponse = ""
            while self.mySerial.inWaiting() > 0:
                responseInBytes = self.mySerial.read(bytesToRead)
                modemResponse += self.byte2str(responseInBytes)
            self.mySerial.flushInput()
            self.state = self.STATE[serialConnection.IDLE]
            if printResponse==True:
                print("<<<<< received:")
                print(modemResponse)
    if self.lookForEndChars(modemResponse)==False:
        self.isResponseEmpty(modemResponse)
    if saveResponseToFile==True:
        responseReadyToSave = self.makeResponseReadyToSave(modemResponse)
    if printResponseStatus==True:
        if self.responseState==self.STATE_RESPONSE[serialConnection.NOTCOMPLETE]:
            print("INFO: End char is missing!!!")
            print()
        elif self.responseState==self.STATE_RESPONSE[serialConnection.EMPTY]:
            print("INFO: Response is EMPTY!!!")
            print()
        elif self.responseState==self.STATE_RESPONSE[serialConnection.UNKNOWN]:
            print("This one should never be printed!!!")
            print()
            print()
        return responseReadyToSave
```

Again, not the whole code.

And my sms.py script:
class sms():

```
def __init__(self, serialGSMclass):
    self.setATE0() #AND OFC PROBLEM "GOES" HERE
    self.setSmsMessageFormat()
    self.setPrefferedSmsMessageStorage()

def setATE0(self):
    command = "ATE0"
    serialGSMclass.send(self, command) #AND HERE
    serialGSMclass.receive(self, False, True, False) #QUESTION 2!
    if serialGSMclass.responseState=="COMPLETE_OK":
        print("Set to ATE0")
    else:
        print("ERROR: Did not set ATE0!!!")
```

Error: 'sms' object has no attribute state

It means that program "thinks" that "self.state" in serialConnection.send() for python isnt serialConnectionObject.state but smsObject.state and it cannot find it because there is noone. Right? But how can I make it work?

And
QUESTION 2:
Why do i have to put self into send() at all? Or mb I shouldn't? Now, when I'm writting it, I think that it might cause the problem (because I kinda pass self from sms into serialConnection)! BUT I did that because before I had it like this:
serialConnectionClass.send(command) and I had this:
ERROR: send() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'
It's kinda like send() NEEDS something more than just one argument. But since send(self, command) caused problem and send(command) does not work either how do I make this work? :D

Comment: This seems like way too much boilerplate. The title of your question is simple, why is the question so complicated? Please decouple the nature of the problem from your actual code and provide us with a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: are sms.py and gmsSMS.py the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Class `sms` you have  (and gave) a parameter `serialGSMclass`. But you did nothing with him. You should do something like that

```
def __init__(self, serialGSMclass):
    self.setATE0() #AND OFC PROBLEM "GOES" HERE
    self.setSmsMessageFormat()
    self.setPrefferedSmsMessageStorage()
    self.serialGSMclass = serialGSMclass

def setATE0(self):
    command = "ATE0"
    self.serialGSMclass.send(self, command) #AND HERE
    self.serialGSMclass.receive(self, False, True, False) #QUESTION 2!
    if self.serialGSMclass.responseState=="COMPLETE_OK":
        print("Set to ATE0")
    else:
        print("ERROR: Did not set ATE0!!!")
```

2: In the class method you must put `self` as the first parameter to use variables, methods, ... of the class instance. Without `self` you muss write `@staticmethod` above the method definition. But you can't use the class variables and method anymore.

Examples:

```
class A:
   def __init__(self, a):
      self.a = a

   def print_a(self):
      print(self.a)

   @staticmethod
   def print_a_static():
      print(self.a)

   @staticmethod
   def print_a_static_2():
      print(a)

a_instance = A(2)               # a_instance is a instance of the class A now and has a variable a=2
a_instance.print_a()            # print the value of a: 2
a_instance.print_a_static()     # Exception: unknown self
a_instance.print_a_static_2()   # Exception: unknown a
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was missing self.serialGSMclass = serialGSMclass in __init__.

Answer (score 0):

Soebody posted an answer that worked, but it's deleted.. I'm sorry I don't remember your Nickname.
What i was missing was in sms.py **init**() script:

```
def __init__(self, serialConnection):
    if not serialConnection:
        raise Exception ("invalid serial connection")
    self.serialConnection = serialConnection
```

and then it worked fine.

Oh, sorry. Was it you, julivico?

Comment: sr, i wanted to write the answer again. because i didn't read your second question